# Logging Unique Request IDs in either Retrofit (and/or OkHttp)

Tags: retrofit, okhttp

When building web services, I like to generate a unique request ID for each request that comes in.  This way, I can include this ID in log messages I generate - which allows my to debug/monitor my service better in production.

When using Retrofit, I want to be able to include this ID in log messages generated by the library.  For example, when setting `RestAdapter.LogLevel.BASIC` on a `RestAdapter`, a log message with the following format is generated:

```
---> HTTP GET https://api.github.com/repos/square/retrofit/contributors
<--- HTTP 200 https://api.github.com/repos/square/retrofit/contributors (938ms)
```

I want to be able to include my generated request ID like the following:

```
1b574532-5f38-4e03-9e0a-c464881a4fd3 ---> HTTP GET https://api.github.com/repos/square/retrofit/contributors
1b574532-5f38-4e03-9e0a-c464881a4fd3 <--- HTTP 200 https://api.github.com/repos/square/retrofit/contributors (938ms)
```

Is there a recipe that'll allow me to do this with Retrofit (and/or OkHttp)?

Comment: With the currently released versions of Retrofit I think you would have the change the actual logging code inside the `RestAdapter`. But there is this commit on github so it seems that there is some major work going on with regards to logging: https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/40bfa340bbff6b18c691f74b40e09f27b98ab920. With OkHttp it should be quite possible, though: https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors

Comment: Sounds like this is the only way.  Thanks a ton @david.mihola !